# Magento2-Fatal error:Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116

Tags: magento2.3, server-setup, transfer

Transfer site from server to dedicated server.

I am getting Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /home/uscvuy32bk5d/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to clear comment before this line in php.ini file:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

**to**

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Comment: In php.ini root folder, i added extension=php_intl.dll.  Same error.

Comment: have you restarted php server & checked ?

Comment: Let me know if that works.

Comment: I restarted the server but Not working

Comment: Are Both the entries for the base-urls (secure und unsecure) under stores > configuration > general > web are secure (https://) domain ?

Comment: What is your php version  ?

Comment: is nothing works check then probably you're missing PHP extension php-intl from your server, try to install it

Comment: Php version 7.2

Comment: Base url : http for both

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl

Comment: How can I install php-intl extension? Can you send the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116964/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-gill).

Answer (score 0):

I did a switch form `PHP 7.3 -> 7.4` and I got the same error. In my case I was missing the `intl` library, so by executing this command:

`sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl`

Fixed my problem .